# How to find the total number of connected graphs on 'n' vertices?

Tags: python

I wanna calculate the number of connected graphs on 8 vertices but not able to write a code.

I tried many times but the result was not accurate. The number of connected graphs on 8 vertices are 11117
but neither of the code I tried give the correct answer.

Comment: It's not clear to me what it is you are even asking for. Do you mean finding the total number of possible connected graphs?

Comment: Yes, MikaelÖhman. I wanna find the total number of possible connected graphs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a broad guideline on how you could do it. It uses the fact that if you raise the adjacency matrix (with full diagonal) to the eighth power, it gives you which nodes are connected (see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864604/checking-connectivity-of-adjacency-matrix))

1. Generate all possible adjacency matrices of size 8.
2. Remove the isomorphic graphs by eliminating identical matrices up to row and column permutations.
3. Raise the matrices to the eighth power.
4. Check if there is a row that is all non-zero (with something like `any(matrix.all(axis=1))`)

Here is a way you could to step 1:

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

def get_pairs(n):
    # this function returns the coordinates 
    # of the top right triangle of the matrix
    ans = []
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(x+1, n):
            ans.append([x, y])
    return ans

n = 8
coords = get_pairs(n)
diagonal = [range(n), range(n)]
for num_edges in range(1, len(coords)+1): # for each number of edges
    for edges in combinations(coords): # We take the possible combinations of coordinates.
        matrix = np.zeros((n, n)) 
        matrix[*zip(*edges)] = 1 # Set the matrix entries of chosen coordinates to 1.
        matrix = matrix + np.transpose(matrix) 
        matrix[*diagonal] = 1
        # Here you can access the adjacency matrix.
```

Note that the code will take very long to run as there are `2**28 = 268435456` such matrices.
I hope this helps!

Comment: I would try this. Thanks for your precious time.